# Laravel 7 Missing required parameters for route

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

When go to this route : `talent/lists`
, I get the following error message

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: talent.ajax] [URI: {_locale}/{role}/talent/ajax]. (View: C:\laragon\www\iccn-intern\Modules\Profile\Resources\views\backOffice\talent\lists.blade.php)
```

My code goes like this

AppConst:

```
  const ROUTE_TALENT_AJAX = 'talent.ajax';
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{role}/talent', 'middleware' => [ 'role:administrator' ]], function() {
  Route::match(['get', 'post', 'patch'], 'ajax', 'TalentController@_ajax_dt_talents')->name( AppConst::ROUTE_TALENT_AJAX );
  Route::get('lists', 'TalentController@lists')->name('talent.list');
```

View:

```
<div class="card-header">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <h3>{{ucwords(trans('profile::talent.list.main_title'))}}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
            <div class="app_customized">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed app_condensed datatable-serverside" 
                    data-urlajax="{{ route( AppConst::ROUTE_TALENT_AJAX) }}" data-func-config="dtconfig_talents">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ucwords(trans('profile::talent.list.name'))}}</th>
                    <th>{{ucwords(trans('profile::talent.list.phone_number'))}}</th>
                    <th>{{ucwords(trans('profile::talent.list.gender'))}}</th>
                    <th>{{ucwords(trans('profile::talent.list.option'))}}</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
```

Controller:

```
protected function _ajax_dt_talents( Request $request ) {
        /**
         * @var User $rowUser
         */
        $rowUser = Auth::user();

        /**
         * @var Talent $rowTalent
         */
        $rowTalent = $rowUser->talent()->first();

        $datatables = new Datatables(new LaravelAdapter);

        $datatables->query("SELECT u.name, t.phone_number, t.gender  FROM talents as t JOIN users as u ON u.id = t.user_id WHERE t.id=". $rowTalent->id);


        $arrData = $datatables->generate()->toArray();
        $arrData['_timestamp'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        return response()->json($arrData);
    }
```

Does anyone have a clue what should i do to fix that? Or another way to show the Talent Table serverside?

Comment: change your function access modifier `protected` to `public`

Comment: @Shahrukh It doesn't fix the problem, still the same error

Comment: Show your route file

Comment: @Shahrukh Yeah, i just edited the routes

Comment: You need to pass 2 parameter on your route

Comment: Yes, now issue is that your are using middleware where you pass `{role}` as a parameter but in your route you are not passing the value of role.

Answer (score 0):

as you route look like this :

`_locale}/{role}/talent/ajax`

when calling

```
{{ route( AppConst::ROUTE_TALENT_AJAX) }}
```

you need at least 2 params, so your route should look like this :

```
{{ route( AppConst::ROUTE_TALENT_AJAX, [$local, $role]) }}
```